# Java GUI Small Paint Program

Tags: java, swing, paint, paintcomponent, jcomponent

This is kind of the same question as my last (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356365/gui-java-program-paint-program)), but I'm still having trouble with getting everything to work properly.  I have the actual GUI to show up now, but nothing is displayed such as my buttons or the content where you paint on. If someone could help, that would be greatly appreciated!!
Thank you!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Paint{

 public static void main(String[] args){
    Win frame = new Win();
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

 }

}

class gui extends JComponent{
 Image image;
 Graphics2D draw;
 int x, y, prevX, prevY;

gui(){
        setDoubleBuffered(false);   
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
                        prevX = e.getX();
                        prevY = e.getY();
                }

        });

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter(){
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
                        x = e.getX();
                        y = e.getY();
                        draw.drawLine(prevX, prevY, x, y);
                        repaint();
                        prevX = x;
                        prevY = y;

                }


        });

}


public void changeColor(Color color)
{
    draw.setPaint(color);
    repaint();
}
public void clear(){
    draw.setPaint(Color.white);
    draw.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
    draw.setPaint(Color.black);
    repaint();
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    if(image == null)
    {
        image = createImage(getSize().width, getSize().height);
        draw = (Graphics2D)image.getGraphics();
        draw.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        clear();
    }

    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
 }
} 





class Win extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    JButton red, green, blue, clear;
    gui gui = new gui();

    Win(){
        super("Paint");
        setSize(500,500);


        Container content=new Container();
        content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        content.add(gui, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        content.setVisible(true);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        content.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(32, 68));
        panel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(32, 68));
        panel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(32, 68));


        red = new JButton("Red");
        green = new JButton("Green");
        blue = new JButton("Blue");
        clear = new JButton("Clear");

        red.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 16));
        green.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,16));
        blue.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 16));

        panel.add(red);
        panel.add(green);
        panel.add(blue);
        panel.add(clear);

        panel.setVisible(true);

        red.addActionListener(this);
        green.addActionListener(this);
        blue.addActionListener(this);
        clear.addActionListener(this);




    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if( e.getSource()==red){
            gui.changeColor(Color.red);
            repaint();
        }
        if( e.getSource()==green){
            gui.changeColor(Color.green);
            repaint();
        }
        if( e.getSource()==blue){
            gui.changeColor(Color.blue);
            repaint();
        }
        if( e.getSource()==clear){
            gui.clear();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You do realise this isn't actually a question - probably your previous one was, but we can't see that here.

Comment: It's easy to find his last question, it's here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356365/gui-java-program-paint-program

Comment: the same question, as in, I still can't get the main content to show up. So the question being: How can I get the main content (panel and paint window) to show up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at that `Win` constructor. You create a lot of components, add them to a lot of panels but none of them is actually added to the `Win` instance.

Since it is that `Win` instance you make visible, it makes sense nothing appears

Further notes:

- Please do not dump all your code here but try to cut it down to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) (with the emphasis on short). For example why showing us the code for 5 buttons if you can reproduce your issue with only one button. Why the code for the `ActionListener` when your problem is that the UI does not show
- There is no need to call `set(xxx)Size`. Use `JFrame#pack` after you have added all components
- Components are visible by default. So there is no need to call `setVisible( true )` on each component you create, as long as you add them to a parent which is already visible
- The use of the `Graphics2D` field in the `gui` class is completely wrong. You should override the `paintComponent` method for custom painting
- The name of the `gui` class violates the Java naming conventions. This makes the code hard to read

Comment: sorry for dumping all of my code, I didn't know where to narrow the problem, but I understand how it can be a nuisance. I really appreciate all of the pointers though! Trying to not pick up bad habits while I learn

Comment: @user1820070 *I didn't know where to narrow the problem* removing pieces of code and see whether the problem still occurs should allow you to narrow down the problem. No good reason that we should do that for you

Comment: This is my second time using this site since last night, I was unaware that is was frowned upon to list the whole code. I figured it would make it a lot easier for whomever to understand what I was trying to do by examining the whole code.

Comment: @user1820070 The [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and the [blog of John Skeet](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) give some good hints on how to post code and how to post a question on this site. Follow those guidelines and your questions will most likely be upvoted instead of downvoted/closed

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to be using your gui class - add this line:

```
frame.add(new Gui());
```

after you set the frame visible (note that you have named your class gui, which is not standard)